# Responsively center SVG element inside another SVG element?

Tags: svg, responsive-design, fullscreen

I'm trying to do something very simple in SVG:

1. Divide the entire viewport into two rectangles
2. Each rectangle should have a width 50% of the viewport's width
3. Each rectangle should have a height 100% of the viewport's height
4. In the center of each rectangle, draw another rectangle 100px wide and 40px high
5. The center of each of these "child" rectangles, for lack of a better term, should be aligned with the center of their respective "parent" rectangles--**at any viewport size**.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve, but using `<text>` elements instead of `<rect>` elements:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">

  <svg x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="100%" overflow="visible">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#363636"></rect>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" text-color="#393939">Sign In</text>
  </svg>

  <svg x="50%" y="0" width="50%" height="100%" overflow="visible">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#999999"></rect>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">Sign Up</text>
  </svg>

</svg>
```

How can I do this with rectangles--or any SVG shape, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the secret to responsive SVG design is to have each object on the screen be its own `<svg>` element. In other words, use `<svg>` as a group tag.

Why? Because `<svg>` elements can be positioned using percentages.

To position the `<svg>` by its center rather than its upper, left-hand corner, use its `transform="translate(dx,dy)"` property.

In the case of our example, putting the text and "child" rectangles inside their own `<svg>` parent, and then transforming that, pulls off the desired effect:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">

  <!-- Left Column -->
  <svg x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="100%" overflow="visible">

    <!-- "Parent" Rectangle -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#363636"></rect>

    <!-- "Child" Rectangle with Text -->
    <svg x="50%" y="50%" width="116" height="40" overflow="visible">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="20" ry="20" fill="#FFFFFF" transform="translate(-58, -25)"></rect>
      <text x="0" y="0" text-color="#393939" transform="translate(-29, 0)">Sign Up</text>
    </svg>

  </svg>

  <!-- Right Column -->
  <svg x="50%" y="0" width="50%" height="100%" overflow="visible">

    <!-- "Parent" Rectangle -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#999999"></rect>

    <!-- "Child" Rectangle with Text -->
    <svg x="50%" y="50%" width="100" height="40" overflow="visible">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="20" ry="20" fill="#FFFFFF" transform="translate(-50, -25)"></rect>
      <text x="0" y="0" text-color="#393939" transform="translate(-25, 0)">Sign In</text>
    </svg>

  </svg>

</svg>
```

( Tested in Mac OS X Chrome 39.0 and iOS 8.1.2 Safari )

Comment: How is this responsive? You say you are transforming the parent, but the transform is applied to the text elements - and then using fixed pixel sizes.

Comment: It's been almost an entire quarter of a year since I've looked at this, but--the root svg element is the one that responds to screen size. The others size themselves relative to that.